# Non-caching DNS client

Tags: unix, dns, monitoring

I want to do NS lookups that do not cache a single thing.  So in essence I want to resolve them all the way through the chain every time I look them up.  Don't care what language it's written in, as long as I can run it on Linux. In the end, my goal is to monitor DNS lookup times for our domains from different locations -- but I need to do it programmatically so that I can record and report on it.  Any ideas or solutions are appreciated.  (Extra credit if I can do it with a shell script and standard unix tools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dig +trace` always goes all the way from the root servers and displays response time for every server in the chain.